# How to create or get an OrganizationServiceProxy instance on a plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is there any way to create an OrganizationServiceProxy instance on a plugin?
I want to execute EnableProxyTypes method passing an assembly which is different from the plugin assembly as the argument of EnableProxyTypes method.
Because I want to have assembly file which has an early bound class and be shared by some plugins and programs.

```
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = (IPluginExecutionContext) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof    (IPluginExecutionContext));
        var factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        var service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        var proxy = (OrganizationServiceProxy)service; //this doesn't work. an error occurs.
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating OrganizationServiceProxy in CRM2011 Plugin to use Early binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490760/creating-organizationserviceproxy-in-crm2011-plugin-to-use-early-binding)

Comment: I don't think you should do so. IOrganizationService should be enough in plugin to complete any activities, as well as work with proxy classes you have to add as a reference to the plugin when building it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a read of this article:

[Walkthrough: Build a Plug-in That Connects to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Using Developer Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg695782.aspx)

In particular the following snippets.

```
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

...

using (var crm = new XrmServiceContext(service))
```